# Loading module from heroku was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: javascript, html, mime

I have an app with an html like that import script like this =>

```
    <script type="module" src="/libs/ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/scripts/login.js"></script>
```

those 2 script look like this

ajax.js

```
export class Ajax {
 //blabla
}
```

login.js

```
import { Ajax } from '../libs/ajax.js'

const loginBtn = document.getElementById('go_login');
const signupBtn = document.getElementById('go_signup');
const ajax = new Ajax();

document.getElementById('signup').onclick = () => {
    const username = document.getElementById('signup_name').value;
    if(username && email && password){
        ajax.post('', {//blabla}) 

}
```

It works ok in local, and I am able to build and run it.

But, when I deploy on heroku, I get the following :

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is
>   enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: Hey @bobby, did you find an solution?

Comment: never, I just gave up